# How to disable specific date on <input type="date"> using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, datepicker

Is there any way to disable specific date on HTML `<input type="date">` using vanilla JavaScript?  All the tutorials that I have read are in jQuery but I want to do it in vanilla JavaScript. For example, to disable unavailable dates in a Hotel booking form.

Comment: You mean not allowing certain dates to be selected? That's a feature that does not exist on the default date pickers using `input` (how exactly would you even specify such a thing on a default picker?)

Comment: *Im making it for a hotel booking form* completely unimportant to the question ... use event handlers, e.g. `change` or `input` (depending on how you want to handle it) - you have jquery code, it's relatively simple to translate that to so called vanilla JS, just understand the different between how jquery handles events and so called vanilla handles events, and the rest writes itself

Comment: The native date picker allows [`min`, `max` and `step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#additional_attributes) to limit dates that can be entered, however disabling a specific date is not supported out of the box.